# How to find the force of a particle at $t=0$ which trajectory equation is $\sigma(t)=\cos(t)\hat{i}+\sin(2t)\hat{j}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, kinematics

Problem:

*A particle of 3 grams of mass follows the trajectory $\sigma(t)=\cos(t)\hat{i}+\sin(2t)\hat{j}$ (units in seconds and centimeters). Compute the force performed over the particle at $t=0$.*

Solution:

The first thing I did was plot the parametric equation on Wolfram|Alpha (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+(cos(t),+sin(2t))):

[image: \sigma(t)=\cos(t)\hat{i}+\sin(2t)\hat{j}]

The section marked with the red figure is where the force must be found.

I know that Newton's law for force is given by $\vec{F}=ma(t)$. In this case $a=3gr$, but how do I find the expression $a(t)$?

Comment: Is this in Irodov?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN, I don't know.

Comment: Acceleration is the second derivative of position.

Comment: @arctictern: This is more of an answer than a hint ...

Answer (score 1):

As arctic tern said, acceleration is the second derivative of position.

Then $\vec{a}(t) = -$cos$(t) \hat{i} - 4$sin$(2t) \hat{j} $.

From there we have that $\vec{F}(t) = m\vec{a}(t) = -3$cos$(t) \hat{i} - 12$sin$(2t) \hat{j}$, so that $\vec{F}(0) = -3\hat{i} - 0\hat{j} = -3\hat{i}$.